# does package need to be in jar for ant build script

Tags: java, ant, jar

does a java package need to be packaged into a jar for ANT to see it on the classpath or can it just be a regular folder structure/directory with .class files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just leave the class files in file system directories - but as normal, that directory hierarchy should match the package structure of the classes.

Basically, an Ant classpath is just like a classpath in a normal Java tool - just with fancier features such as property substitution. Ultimately in most cases it'll be *passed* to a normal Java tool in just the same way as you'd specify it on a command-line, so anything that's supported on the command-line is likely to work in Ant too.

Comment: ok thank you, but im getting "package does not exist" error... not sure why

Comment: @AbdulAhmad: Well we can't really help you without knowing any details. If you turn on more verbose logging you should see more details about what Ant is doing.

Comment: yea I know, I apologize, but its for work and they dont want us posting any type of code snippets online, and I've turned on -v and I'm looking at a log file, thank you for the help

Comment: @AbdulAhmad: Your edit asks a second, separate question. One question per post, please.